# Killing Root Processes in Android

Tags: android, service, process, su, pppd

I'm building an Android application that starts a process by calling su and sending it a command, along these lines:

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" );
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream( su.getOutputStream() );

out.writeChars( "pppd /dev/pts/0" );
out.flush();
```

When I want to stop the service and kill the pppd process, I'm currently running `busybox killall pppd` through `su` like the initial call to pppd.  Simply calling `su.destroy()` fails, even if I use `pppd /dev/pts/0 nodetach` in the first call, which prevents pppd from forking and creating a background process.  `killall` works, but it could break other applications that rely on pppd.

I'd greatly prefer a scalpel that lets me eliminate the pppd process directly, but short of running `ps`, searching through the PID's, and calling `kill`, there doesn't appear to be a decent solution.

Is there a reasonably clean way to kill a process that's been started through `su` on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that as I progressed on implementing the ppp connection, I no longer needed to manually kill the pppd process.  Simply sending a Terminate-Request tells the pppd process that it can close its connection, and the process shuts down after that.

Regarding the underlying problem, killing a root process nicely, I wasn't unable to find a decent solution.  The most effective option still seems to be running `busybox killall pppd` or manually searching for the process by using `ps` and basic Java string manipulation.